# Visual Studio Apache Cordova APPHOST9603

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

I keep getting an APPHOST9603 error when I run my Apache Cordova App in Visual Studio 2015. This gets marked as an error in the Console. Every time I run the app, there are more APPHOST Errors.

This is the error description:

> APPHOST9603: "Can’t load the ActiveX plug-in that has the class ID
>   classID. Apps can't load ActiveX controls."

The reason of this error is described in the [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj860457.aspx) of Microsoft:

> Windows Runtime apps using JavaScript don't support custom Microsoft ActiveX controls. [...]

The problem is that this errors happen since I created the blank project. I even deleted most of the HTML inside `index.html`, leaving just a white screen.

Does anyone know how to solve this error? Maybe Cordova is creating some kind of file somewhere else, which gets bigger every time I run my application?

Comment: Try clear the cordova cache: in vs2015-> tools->options->tools for apache cordova->clear cordova cache.

Comment: @ElvisXia I have tried that several times with no success.

Comment: Could you post the blank app that gets this error?

Comment: What target are you building to? Windows? Ripple? Android?

Comment: I have tried Windows and Ripple with no difference.